# Retrieve a specific field from taxonomy term through advanced custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, advanced-custom-fields

I've set up a custom field which appears in a taxonomy terms page. I am trying pull an image associated with the custom taxonomy term directly

However the page in which it is being displayed is a template page. I think I need to pass the post ID before pulling the specific image, but how do you do that for a custom taxonomy?

The custom taxonomy is 'manufacture', and the term id is e.g 1, the image field id is 'image_toc' and I have set ACF to image url. I've read the page on "how-to/how-to-get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/" but I don't really understand what I'm supposed to replace with what. I am using things along the lines of:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('image_toc', 'I am giving term id here'); ?>" />
```

But nothing is happening. No image and no path in the source code.

Comment: What's the name of the custom taxonomy?

Comment: The custom taxonomy is 'manufacture', and the term id is  1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To retrieve a field from ACF for a term (instead of, for example, a post), you should use the taxonomy name, followed by an underscore, followed by the term ID instead of the post ID when calling `the_field` or `get_field`. Assuming you want to retrieve the field `image_toc` for the taxonomy `mytax` and term ID `$termid` that would be:

```
<img src="<?php the_field( 'image_toc', 'mytax_' . $termid ); ?>" />
```

In your case, this would amount to

```
<img src="<?php the_field( 'image_toc', 'manufacture_1' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: Its working great and exactly I need. I cannot give you +1 because of privilege.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, you're welcome!