# How to use acf field value to order category?

Tags: categories, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to order category by acf field value. How can I achieve this using acf filed value?

[image]

```
    $categories = get_categories('taxonomy=toc_category');
    $sorted_cats = array();
    foreach($categories as $cat){
        $ordr = get_field('order', 'toc_category' . '_' . $cat->term_id);
        $sorted_cats[$ordr] = $cat;

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($cat);
        echo $cat->name; // it not returns expexted output
    }
    krsort($sorted_cats);
    return $sorted_cats;
```

Comment: Do you want to try to get acf filed of category? First you let me know how did you name acf fields?

Comment: I want to display category name order by acf field value. I have added acf text filed to category. In which i had stored value like 1 for category 1,2 for category 2.

Comment: Okay, My question is what is the name of order of acf `'toc_category' . '_' . $cat->term_id`.

Comment: As you mentioned that you have the category, category1, and category2.
there should name for acf field `order`.

Comment: Please this link hope it will helpful for you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/151879/137328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this code.

```
$categories = get_terms('toc_category');
$sorted_cats = array();
foreach($categories as $cat){
    $ordr = get_field('order', 'toc_category_'.$cat->term_id);
    $sorted_cats[$ordr] = $cat->name;
}
krsort($sorted_cats);
return $sorted_cats;
```

Comment: How to print cat name under foreach loop? I have tryid with print_r($sorted_cats) but it not returns title.

Comment: @Abhee use this code inside the loop and put code just above the "}"    echo "<pre>"; print_r($sorted_cats);

Comment: foreach($categories as $cat){
    $ordr = get_field('order', 'toc_category_'.$cat->term_id);
    $sorted_cats[$ordr] = $cat->name;
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($sorted_cats);
}